# Strange postgresql behavior

Tags: postgresql

can someone explain me why it works like this?

```
=> select client_id from clients_to_delete;
ERROR:  column "client_id" does not exist at character 8
```

but, when putting this inside an IN()...

```
=> select * from orders where client_id in(select client_id from clients_to_delete);
```

it works! and select all rows in the orders table. Same when running delete/update.
Why it doesn't produce an error like before?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In this query

```
SELECT  *
FROM    orders
WHERE   client_id IN
        (
        SELECT  client_id
        FROM    clients_to_delete
        )
```

`client_id` is taken from the outer table (`orders`), since there is no field with such name in the inner table (`clients_to_delete`):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    orders
WHERE   orders.client_id IN 
        (
        SELECT  orders.client_id
        FROM    clients_to_delete
        )
```